# How to create a multiple mySQL insert from an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a series of `hash` in the form of `a,b,c,d,e` and I do it through the following

```
$hashes = array();
while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))) {
    $hashes[] = $row['hash'];
} 

$_SESSION['hashes'] = implode(',', $hashes); // a,b,c,d,e
```

My question is how can I add a multiple Insert like below?

```
INSERT INTO alerts_data (alerts_data_id, alerts_data_hash) 
VALUES 
('$last insert id', 'hash 1'),
('$last insert id', 'hash 2')
('$last insert id', 'hash 3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Prepared Statements in MySQLi and loop the insert query to insert multiple records.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


// prepare and bind
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO alerts_data (alerts_data_id, alerts_data_hash) VALUES (?, ?)");

$hashes = array();
while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))) {
    $hashes[] = $row['hash'];
} 


foreach($hashes as $key => $hashe)
{
    $stmt->bind_param($key, $hashe['hash']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```